# plain text password in c# web app

Tags: model-view-controller, passwords

Am I right in saying that if I have a plain text password (say to connect to an SMTP mail server) in one of my c# controllers, there is no way for an attacker to view this (or the rest of the server side code for that matter) unless server security is broken?

I am on shared hosting so I can't do anything with IIS to encrypt web config (as far as I am aware). If this is such bad practice, does anyone have any suggestions as to how to best tackle this issue?

Comment: Anyone who can read files on your server can read that password.  Who that is depends on the server admins & configuration.

Comment: ok thanks, so if I trust my hosting provider then I am OK?

Comment: @mattbloke: The general rule is, *never* store passwords in plain text.  ***Never***.  If they're stored in plain text, they're not secure.  Period.

Comment: @David: If you need to use the password, there is no alternative.  Encrypting it won't help because the server needs to decrypt it anyway.

Comment: @SLaks: Ah, re-reading I see what the question is asking now.  The password isn't necessarily "stored" in that same sense as I was thinking, it's kept in perhaps a config file for the application to connect to a service.  In that case, yes, it kind of needs to be there.  Hmm, interesting question.  It can be obscured, but in this case it's really a matter of trusting the server's security to secure the configuration file.  (And using a one-off non-reused password.)  "Shared hosting" may give me pause in such a situation, unless the host is really trusted.

Comment: all my persisted password are hashed appropriately, it is just these 'connection' ones I am struggling with what to do with. Is it better to have them in web.config than in controlleR?

Comment: @mattbloke: As a matter of not hard-coding things I'd leave them in the config file.  The controller *code* doesn't need to be on the server at all, but any string value can easily be extracted from the compiled `.dll`.  For service account passwords like this at the very least you want to make sure nothing else anywhere uses that same password.  (For example, don't re-use your email password or banking password or anything like that.)  The web server should indeed secure access to these files, and if the server is compromised then the attacker does indeed have that password.

Answer (score 0):

> If this is such bad practice, does anyone have any suggestions as to how to best tackle this issue?

It is a bad practice.  While you can't prevent an attacker who can read files on the server (or the backups) from figuring it out (quickly, if they're good), you can force them to spend more time and effort in reading your code/disassembled application and your config files both.

Are you allowed to set the SMTP password yourself?  Store in your config file a very high number of iterations (millions; it's just startup delay!), a truly random** salt of 8 bytes, and a long, random "password" (binary is better).  In your code, when the application is started, read those values, add a hardcoded string of 8 truly random bytes to the salt (a "pepper"), and use the [RFC2898DeriveBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to generate the actual SMTP password (which you're likely to have to encode with Base64).  Don't ask for more than 20 bytes of RFC2898DeriveByutes output; that's using SHA-1 as the native hash.  You will obviously need to do this prior to changing the SMTP password :).

Regardless of your ability to change the SMTP, you can always encrypt the password, using the above RFC2898DeriveBytes to generate a 128 bit key for use with AES-128 in, say, the [AesCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aescryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class if you're on .NET 3.5 or up, which is one of the few [FIPS 140-2 compliant encryption classes](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e0b4493f-6e20-4b75-a118-6b6e5d26a2a6/which-classes-call-fipscertified-algorithm-code?forum=netfxbcl) in .NET.

If you want a way to handle this that prevents simply reading files from finding out the password, you'll need to look at something like an HSM (hardware security module) or other secure key storage provider outside of your appliance.  Be prepared to open your wallet!

** In .NET, use the [RNGCryptoServiceProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to generate random bytes for crypto use.

Comment: thank you for your very detailed answer. I will look into this, I fear it may be beyond my skillset at this moment in time. Without wishing to ask for the answer, is there a good source that covers most/all of the above in detail that I can follow step by step?...and yes I can set the password to whatever I want